# Question about a finite Galois extension over a field of characteristic $0$

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

I have a question from an old algebra prelim in Galois theory and would like to know the best or quickest method in proving it. The question is that suppose $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$. Suppose that $K/F$ is a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G$. Prove that if $a \in K$ and $g(a)-a \in F \text{ } \forall g \in G$, then $a \in F$.

So far, here's what I know. $K/F$ is the splitting field of a separable polynomial with coefficients in $F$. Also, $G= \text{Aut}(K/F)$, that is, $G$ is the set of automorphisms of $K$ that fix the base field $F$; in other words, this is the collection of all $g \in G$ such that $g:K \rightarrow K,  g(a)=a \text{ }\forall a \in F$. I'm not sure, but would this be of any help in at least getting me started? Also, is $a$ a root of the separable polynomial for which $K/F$ is its splitting field? Any helpful suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\in K$.
Then $$a=\frac{\sum_{g\in G}g(a)-\sum_{g\in G} (g(a)-a)}{|G|}$$ 
shows that $a\in F$. (The division by $|G|$ is why we need characteristic $0$).

Comment: It seems that this answer is based on traces and norms which I never remember discussing in any algebra course involving Galois theory.